# I can't get shadows to appear around my custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, layer, shadow

```
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -2.0);

cell.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.layer.bounds].CGPath;
```

I have been trying to get a shadow to appear around my cells, however I haven't had any luck. I've even tried ordering the zPosition of my cells to see if it works, and nothing. What am I missing?

I want to be able to draw my shadows so the cell with index.row = x appears to be above the cell with index.row = x-1

Answer (score 0):

You might get this to work to some extent by setting the layer's `masksToBounds` to NO. But don't. Don't do any of what you're doing. What you're trying to do is a really bad idea, because you are forcing the render tree to constantly rerender the shadow while the table scrolls, which will cause a low frame rate and stuttering of the scroll.

Comment: What do you recommend I do then?

Comment: I don't know what you _want_ to do. What I do is draw the shadow internally as part of the way the cell draws its contents.

Comment: So you draw your shadows in a drawRect function?

Comment: I added more to my question

Comment: Actually what I do is draw my shadows into a UIImage and make a UIImageView containing that image the background view of the cells. So the best way to do what you're describing might be to draw something that _looks_ like the shadow of the previous cell on the next cell.